# How to set the data of WinJS.UI.Repeater control in JS code?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-metro, repeater, store

I'm developing a Windows Store Application using JavaScript.

How to set the data of WinJS.UI.Repeater control in JS code? It's a very easy question but I don't know how to do.
This is my HTML:

```
<div id="imgRepeater" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Repeater">
   <img data-win-bind="src: src" />
</div>
```

This is my JS code:

```
WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/itemDetail/itemDetail.html", {
    ready: function (element, options) {
        var imgSrcArr = 
        [
           { src: '/img/a.jpg' }
        ];            
        var imgRepeater = element.querySelector("#imgRepeater");            
        imgRepeater.data = new WinJS.Binding.List(imgSrcArr);
    }
});
```

However, no item shows in the repeater div.

What's wrong with the code?

BTW: I don't like the following code:

```
<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Repeater" data-win-options="{data: Data.items}">
```

It seems to use a global variable 'Data.items'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by myself, the last line should be:

```
imgRepeater.winControl.data = new WinJS.Binding.List(imgSrcArr);
```

Comment: You can accept you own answer as correct which will close the question for you.